# Put left and right elements in the same line using css

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, line

I need to put this little logo in the right side of the site.
This is how looks now:

[image]

And I need this:

[image]

I'm using this CSS code:

```
.term-151 .page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title:after {
content: "";

display: inline-block;


background:  url(logourl.jpg here) no-repeat;
width: 30px;
    background-size: contain;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
```

Any idea how to achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use float, and remove position: absolute from that.

```
float:right
```

But from what I see that part of the logo is inside background.
You need to include as standalone img tag and the use the float.

And use that on before selector not the:after

```
.term-151 .page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title
```

Please try to do this, without the float: right.

```
.page-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not working Pipo, but thanks anyway. With your instructions the logo goes above the title ;)

Comment: Show me your HTML of that element

Comment: .term-151 .page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title:after {
content: "";

display: inline-block;


background:  url(https://www.kametoys.cl/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/dc_logo_cat_.png) no-repeat;
width: 30px;
 background-size: contain;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
 margin-left: 10px;
} 

   </style>
  <style>

Comment: I have altered my answer

Comment: Not a dig, this is the correct answer, but the standard method of doing this now is using `flex`.

Comment: That is true, but only if somebody want's to use the flexbox system. I still see people doing inline-block grids :)

Comment: I tried with the updated answer but the logo keeps over the title (DC Comics) :(

Comment: <div class="shop-loop-head">
 <div class="woodmart-woo-breadcrumbs">
     <nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb"><a href="https://www.kametoys.cl" class="breadcrumb-link breadcrumb-link-last">Inicio</a><span class="breadcrumb-last"> DC Comics</span></nav>  
  <p class="woocommerce-result-count">
 Mostrando 12 de 90 resultados</p>
 </div>
 <div class="woodmart-shop-tools">
     <div class="woodmart-show-sidebar-btn">
    <span class="woodmart-side-bar-icon"></span>
    <span>Show sidebar</span>
   </div>

Comment: That is not the same element